# Running into a weird issue in Pine script array where length of array keeps on increasing

Tags: arrays, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am testing array feature in TradingView and trying to print data in a table. I am running into a weird    issue where the length of the array becomes very large and am not able to figure out why.

I create a new float array and push a number into the array. Just one number and when I print the size of the array in the table (last line of code), the size comes up as 7776.

If I try to print the array, I get the following error -

> Study error: Error on bar 7775: String is too long 23328, max allowed length is 4096.

Can someone please suggest what is going on here?

```
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//@version=5

indicator("test indicator", overlay=false)

var test_array = array.new_float()
var tt = 5
array.push(id = test_array, value = 5)

var groupPanel = 'test table'
string table_vertical_pos = input.string('bottom', 'Panel position', inline='11', options=['top', 'middle', 'bottom'], group=groupPanel)
string table_horizontal_pos = input.string('right', '', inline='11', options=['left', 'center', 'right'], group=groupPanel)

text_color = color.black
text_color_white = color.white

fn_fill_header(_id, _row) => 
    table.cell(table_id=_id, column=0, row=_row, text='Criteria', width=0, height=0, text_color=text_color_white, text_size=size.small, bgcolor=color.rgb(92, 92, 94))
    table.cell(table_id=_id, column=1, row=_row, text='', width=0, height=0, text_color=text_color_white, text_size=size.small, bgcolor= color.rgb(92, 92, 94))

fn_fill_value(_id, _row, criteria, value, _color_value) => 
    table.cell(table_id=_id, column=0, row=_row, text=criteria, width=0, height=0, text_color=text_color, text_size=size.small, bgcolor=color.white)
    table.cell(table_id=_id, column=1, row=_row, text=value, width=0, height=0, text_color=text_color, text_size=size.small, bgcolor=_color_value)

var T = table.new(
     position= table_vertical_pos + "_" + table_horizontal_pos, columns=2, rows=10, bgcolor=color.white, 
     frame_color=color.gray, frame_width=2, border_color=color.gray, border_width=1)


if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    fn_fill_header(T, 0)
    fn_fill_value(T, 1, 'test', str.tostring(test_array),  color.rgb(255, 255, 255))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the array without the `var` keyword (and the value of the variable won't persist with every execution).

```
test_array = array.new_float()
```

##### Explanation

What you described happens because you declared the `test_array` using the `var` keyword. The script executes on every bar for historical bars, and when you use the `var` keyword to declare a variable, the value given to the variable persists with each execution.

Better explained in [Variable declarations](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html) and [Execution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html#pageexecutionmodel) sections of the pine-script docs.

So, in your case, a new element gets added to the array with the `array.push(...)` and the array just keeps growing with every execution.